# Default PDF export in IR doesn't include more added number of columns

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-19.2

Default PDF export in IR doesn't include more added number of columns. Some times with more data PDF itself is doenloading as 1kb and not showing any data on screen.

I have almost 15 columns in my report which is getting cut from right side of report if we include all column names.

Is there any workaround to get this resolved within APEX?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The PDF page width is too small to render all columns. PDF always has a fixed width & height per page. There are two solutions I can think of:

- You can customize the PDF page width and height using the print attributes of the Interactive Report.
- You could also consider using a smaller font size.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is a solution but not be universal, it will not adjust automatically.